# Regex to get file extension - LUA

Tags: python, regex

Input: file.exe
Result: exe

Input: xyz.pdf
Result: pdf

Test Case:  I want to select the file extension
I tried the regex `\.[^.]+$`.

However, with above regex the (.)dot is also get selected e.g [.]pdf, [.]exe. How can I negate the dot?

Comment: Try this: `[^.]+$`

Comment: Why is this tagged as Lua???

Answer (score 2):

you can use a [`positive lookbehind assertion`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-22), which means the regex checks the `.` is there, but doesn't capture it as part of the match.

try this:

```py
import re
m = re.search(r'(?<=\.)[^.]+$', 'file.pdf')
print(m.group(0))
```

Output:

```
pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

just delete the first `\.` part like this :

```
[^.]+$
```

Input: `xyz.pdf` 
Result: `pdf`

Comment: Ya, however, it will select whole string if it does not have (.) dot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use just .replace()

Like below:

```
result =result.replace('.','')
```

nasty but will work

Answer (score 0):

Use `\.([^\.]+)$` and then use the group selection mechanism of whatever refectory system you are using to select the first group. Often the 0th group is the entire pattern, including the dot in your case, and the first, AKA 1st, is the first pattern in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You should use () around the item you want to select to create a group, then you can select only the group. In python it would look like this:

```
value = re.search('\.([^.]+)$', 'file.pdf').group(1)
```

This is actually pretty cool to do replace in multiple files with various tools that support regex find/replace.
For example to swap the first two characters in a file name, a regex that would work would look something like this:

```
^(.)(.)(.*)$
```

and for the replace regex you would have:

```
\2\1\3
```

In some find-replace dialogs the groups are defined as \1 and in others as $1.

Comment: Why using flag `re.IGNORECASE` as there're no letters in the regex?

Comment: Indeed, it's not needed. I removed it.